# Recursive query in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I've looked on some recursive queries here, but haven't found my problem. In addition to that I'm new to postgreSQL.

I have the following table with example data:

```
number  numberto    ab  st  kz  pv
112     200                 
140     210                 
200     210                 
210     220         f2  140 H   2011
220                 f2  140 H   2011
```

The query will be a bit more complicated, but this is the part I can't solve. `numberto` refers to another `number` and then maybe again. I can be that this chain continues about four or five times.

Some day the other four coloumns are then `NOT NULL` and filled with letters and/or numbers. If ab has content, then the other three will have it too. If the last coloumns are filled, `numberto` can refer further, but will remain the same, so it's able to stop there.

My problem: I need to make a recursive query of one number, that then searches `numberto` as many times as needed until e.g. `ab` is then filled and get an output of them.

How can I achieve this?

---

```
SELECT version();
```

> PostgreSQL 9.2.6 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973], 64-bit

Comment: Please show a useful sample of the data, at least enough to show one complete case (input and expected output). Also give your PostgreSQL version please.

Comment: I tried to add sample data and add the version(); output. Please tell me if I can improve this answer. :)

Comment: OK, so you want to walk up the numberto -> number chain until you find non-null data columns. Correct?

Comment: Yessir. :) That's what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty simple recursive query, you just stop when you see a non-null row in the recursive term.

Given [the following sample table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/41a9e/3):

```
WITH RECURSIVE chain AS
(
  -- Start with the row with number=140
  SELECT number, numberto, ab, st, kz, pv
  FROM numbers n
  WHERE n.number = 140
  UNION ALL
  -- and iteratively fetch the 'numberto' id'd row
  SELECT n.number, n.numberto, n.ab, n.st, n.kz, n.pv
  FROM chain c
  INNER JOIN numbers n ON (c.numberto = n.number)
  -- unless we've already found a non-null col in our last iteration
  WHERE c.ab IS NULL
)
-- Find any non-null result.
SELECT *
FROM chain c
WHERE c.ab IS NOT NULL;
```

should do the trick, where `n.number = 140` is your start condition.

Iteration stops if you find a non-null col, or if you have a NULL numberto or non-matching numberto (as the inner join will add no rows).

Comment: I tried this now a few hours... are you sure that you can refer in the second SELECT to "n."? Because my SQL program only accepts "c." there as a reference...

Comment: @Trollwut Absolutely certain; follow the SQLFiddle link that demonstrates that it runs as written. Repeating it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/41a9e/3

Comment: Yessir, also with my postgreSQL version it works. But I've got a problem, that one of the rows are actually LEFT JOINed... then I don't get it to work. Despite of that, your answer is right - I will work on that tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, your answer totally fits to my question, so it is right. I'll open another question for the JOIN issue.